# How to fix "Could not find com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:core:1.1.0." (gdx-websockets)

Tags: websocket, libgdx

I am pretty new to this and I'm just trying to create a simple websocket without anything else using com.github.czyzby.websocket.WebSocket;.

This is my html laucher:

```
    @Override
    public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
            // Resizable application, uses available space in browser
            return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(true);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener createApplicationListener () {
            GwtWebSockets.initiate();
            return new GameClass();
    }
```

My GameClass:

```
public class GameClass extends Game {

    public GameClass() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        WebSocket socket = WebSockets.newSocket(WebSockets.toWebSocketUrl("localHost", 8080));
        socket.setSendGracefully(true);
        socket.addListener(new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
                System.out.println("Opened!");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onClose(WebSocket webSocket, WebSocketCloseCode code, String reason) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String packet) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] packet) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        
    }
```

My build.gradle

```
 buildscript { 
    repositories {
        google() 
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }      
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16'
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'
    }
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    version = '1.0'
    group = 'com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets'
    
    ext {
        appName = "my-gdx-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.15'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "de.golfgl.gdxgamesvcs:gdx-gamesvcs-core-gamejolt:1.1.0"
        api "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-desktop:1.3.0"
        api "com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:common:1.1.0"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "org.gretty"

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "de.golfgl.gdxgamesvcs:gdx-gamesvcs-core:1.1.0:sources"
        api "de.golfgl.gdxgamesvcs:gdx-gamesvcs-core-gamejolt:1.1.0:sources"
        api "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-html:1.3.0"
        api "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-html:1.3.0:sources"
        api "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-core:1.3.0:sources"
        api "com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:core:1.1.0:sources"
        api "com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:html:1.1.0"
        api "com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:html:1.1.0:sources"
        api "com.github.tommyettinger:jbump:1.0.1:sources"
        api "com.kotcrab.vis:vis-ui:1.4.11:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "de.golfgl.gdxgamesvcs:gdx-gamesvcs-core:1.1.0"
        api "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-core:1.3.0"
        api "com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:core:1.1.0"
        api "com.github.tommyettinger:jbump:1.0.1"
        api "com.kotcrab.vis:vis-ui:1.4.11"
        api "com.esotericsoftware.spine:spine-libgdx:3.8.55.1" 
    }
}
}
```

When I run it on desktop everything is fine, but when I run *superdev* or *dist* the following error occurrs:

> Task :core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets:core:1.1.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :core

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

What exactly is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The libgdx installer uses 1.1.0 for all com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-websockets dependencies which don't seem to exist.

Replace with 1.9.10.3 or later number published on the github page https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets